# Restarting Continuous Recognition doesn't listen to microphone

Tags: node.js, azure, text-to-speech, speech

I'm using `IntentRecognizer` and `SpeechSynthesizer` from Microsoft Cognitive Speech SDK in a elctron app where I'm using `stopContinuousRecognitionAsync` while SpeechSynthesis is running and after the systhesis stops, I'm starting the recognition again with `startContinuousRecognitionAsync`.

The function runs properly with callback but doesn't listen to anything I say anymore and keeps firing `SpeechSDK.ResultReason.NoMatch`. Here's my code:

```
const SpeechSDK = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
const speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(LUIS_API_KEY, COGNITIVE_SERVICE_REGION);

class CognitiveSpeech {
    constructor() {
      speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US"; //put language from settings later
      var lm = SpeechSDK.LanguageUnderstandingModel.fromAppId(remote.process.env.LUIS_APP_ID);
      var audioConfig  = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
      recognizer = new SpeechSDK.IntentRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
      recognizer.addAllIntents(lm);
  
      recognizer.recognizing = (s, e) => {
          console.log(`RECOGNIZING: Text=${e.result.text}`, e);
      };
      
      recognizer.recognized = (s, e) => {
        console.log("(continuation) Reason: " + SpeechSDK.ResultReason[e.result.reason]);
        switch (e.result.reason) {
          case SpeechSDK.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
            console.log(" Text: " + e.result.text);
            break;
          case SpeechSDK.ResultReason.RecognizedIntent:
            console.log(" Text: " + e.result.text + " IntentId: " + e.result.intentId);
            ///
               DO WORK
               this.synthesizeSpeech('Sure thing');
            ///
            break;
          case SpeechSDK.ResultReason.NoMatch:
            var noMatchDetail = SpeechSDK.NoMatchDetails.fromResult(e.result);
            if(SpeechSDK.NoMatchReason[noMatchDetail.reason] != 'InitialSilenceTimeout')
              console.log(" NoMatchReason: " + SpeechSDK.NoMatchReason[noMatchDetail.reason]);
            break;
          case SpeechSDK.ResultReason.Canceled:
            var cancelDetails = SpeechSDK.CancellationDetails.fromResult(e.result);
            console.log(" CancellationReason: " + SpeechSDK.CancellationReason[cancelDetails.reason]);
          
          if (cancelDetails.reason === SpeechSDK.CancellationReason.Error) {
            console.log(": " + cancelDetails.errorDetails);
          }
        break;
        }
      };
      
      recognizer.canceled = (s, e) => {
          console.log(`CANCELED: Reason=${e.reason}`);
      
          if (e.reason == CancellationReason.Error) {
              console.log(`"CANCELED: ErrorCode=${e.errorCode}`);
              console.log(`"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=${e.errorDetails}`);
              console.log("CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
          }
      
          recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
      };
      
      recognizer.sessionStopped = (s, e) => {
          console.log("Session stopped event.");
          recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
      };
    }

    startRecognition() {
        recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync(()=>{
          console.log('Listenning...');
        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
        
    }

    stopRecognition() {
        recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync(()=>{
          console.log('Stopped Speech Recognition');
        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }

    synthesizeSpeech(string) {
      this.stopRecognition();
      const speechSynthesisConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(COGNITIVE_API_KEY, COGNITIVE_SERVICE_REGION);
      const audioSynthesisConfig = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultSpeakerOutput();
      const synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechSynthesisConfig, audioSynthesisConfig);
      synthesizer.speakSsmlAsync(
        '<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xml:lang="en-US">\
            <voice name="en-US-AriaRUS">\
              <mstts:express-as style="chat">'
                  +string+
              '</mstts:express-as>\
            </voice>\
        </speak>', //put voice from settings letter
          result => {
              if (result) {
                if (result.errorDetails) {
                  console.error(result.errorDetails);
                } else {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                }
                this.startRecognition();
                synthesizer.close();
              }
          },
          error => {
              console.log(error);
              synthesizer.close();
          });
    }
}
```

can anybody help me with what's wrong in this picture?

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that you're not getting the callbacks you expect in the order you expect. I was able to get the following working:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript Quickstart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:13px;">
  <!-- <uidiv> -->
  <div id="content">
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><h1 style="font-weight:500;">Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript Quickstart</h1></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><button id="startRecognitionBtn">Start recognition</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><button id="stopRecognitionBtn">Stop recognition</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">Results</td>
        <td><textarea id="phraseDiv" style="display: inline-block;width:500px;height:200px"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- </uidiv> -->

  <!-- <speechsdkref> -->
  <!-- Speech SDK reference sdk. -->
  <script src="https://aka.ms/csspeech/jsbrowserpackageraw"></script>
  <!-- </speechsdkref> -->

  <!-- <quickstartcode> -->
  <!-- Speech SDK USAGE -->
  <script>
    // status fields and start button in UI
    var phraseDiv;
    var startRecognitionBtn, stopRecognitionBtn;
    var SpeechSDK;
    var speechConfig;
    var recognizer, synthesizer;
    var textToSpeak;

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      startRecognitionBtn = document.getElementById("startRecognitionBtn");
      stopRecognitionBtn = document.getElementById("stopRecognitionBtn");
      phraseDiv = document.getElementById("phraseDiv");

      const getSpeechConfig = () => {
        if (!speechConfig) {
          speechConfig = new SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("KEY", "REGION");
          speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";
        }
        return speechConfig;
      };

      stopRecognitionBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        startRecognitionBtn.disabled = false;
        if(!!recognizer) {
          recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync(
            () => {
            },
            function (err) {
              startRecognitionBtn.disabled = false;
              stopRecognitionBtn.disabled = false;
              phraseDiv.innerHTML += err;
              window.console.log(err);

              recognizer.close();
              recognizer = undefined;
            });
        }
      });
      startRecognitionBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        startRecognitionBtn.disabled = true;
        stopRecognitionBtn.disabled = false;
        phraseDiv.innerHTML = "";

        var sc = getSpeechConfig();
        var lm = SpeechSDK.LanguageUnderstandingModel.fromAppId("APP_ID");

        var audioConfig  = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
        recognizer = new SpeechSDK.IntentRecognizer(sc, audioConfig);
        recognizer.addAllIntents(lm);
        recognizer.canceled = function (_, event) {
          window.console.log(event);
          if (event.reason === sdk.CancellationReason.Error) {
              window.console.log(event.errorDetails);
          }
        };
        recognizer.recognizing = (_, event) => {
          console.log('(recognizing)', { text: event.result.text });
          //textToSpeak = event.result.text;
          textToSpeak = "Sure thing";
          phraseDiv.innerHTML = event.result.text;
        };

        recognizer.recognized = (_, event) => {
          console.log(`(recognized)  Reason: ${sdk.ResultReason[event.result.reason]} Text: ${event.result.text}`);
          startRecognitionBtn.disabled = false;
          startRecognitionBtn.disabled = false;
          phraseDiv.innerHTML = event.result.text;
        };

        recognizer.sessionStarted = (_, event) => {
          console.log(`(sessionStarted) SessionId: ${event.sessionId}`);
          textToSpeak = "";
        };

        recognizer.sessionStopped = (_, event) => {
          console.log(`(sessionStopped) SessionId: ${event.sessionId}`);
          startRecognitionBtn.disabled = false;
        };

        recognizer.speechStartDetected = (_, event) => {
          console.log(`(speechStartDetected) SessionId: ${event.sessionId}`);
        };

        recognizer.speechEndDetected = (_, event) => {
          console.log(`(speechEndDetected) SessionId: ${event.sessionId}`);
          startRecognitionBtn.disabled = false;
          recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync(
            () => {},
            function (err) {
              startRecognitionBtn.disabled = false;
              stopRecognitionBtn.disabled = false;
              phraseDiv.innerHTML += err;
              window.console.log(err);

              recognizer.close();
              recognizer = undefined;
            });
          startSynthesis();
        };

        startRecognition();
      });

      const startRecognition = () => {
        recognizer?.startContinuousRecognitionAsync(
          undefined,
          function (err) {
            startRecognitionBtn.disabled = false;
            phraseDiv.innerHTML += err;
            window.console.log(err);

            recognizer.close();
            recognizer = undefined;
          });
      };

      const startSynthesis = () => {
        if(!synthesizer) {
          var sc2 = getSpeechConfig();
          
          var player = new SpeechSDK.SpeakerAudioDestination();
          player.onAudioEnd = function (_) {
            window.console.log("playback finished");
            phraseDiv.innerHTML += "playback finished" + "\r\n";
          };

          var audioOutConfig  = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromSpeakerOutput(player);

          synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(sc2, audioOutConfig);
        }
        phraseDiv.innerHTML += `detected spoken phrase: ${textToSpeak}\r\n`;
        synthesizer.speakSsmlAsync(
          `<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xml:lang="en-US">\
              <voice name="en-US-AriaRUS">\
                <mstts:express-as style="chat">${textToSpeak}</mstts:express-as>\
              </voice>\
          </speak>`, //put voice from settings letter,
          (result) => {          
            if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted) {
              phraseDiv.innerHTML += "synthesis finished" + "\r\n";
            } else if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.Canceled) {
              phraseDiv.innerHTML += "synthesis failed. Error detail: " + result.errorDetails;
            }
            window.console.log(result);
            closeSynth();
          },
          (err) => {
            window.console.log(err);
            closeSynth();
          });
      };

      const closeSynth = () => {
        synthesizer.close();
        synthesizer = undefined;
      };

      if (!!window.SpeechSDK) {
        SpeechSDK = window.SpeechSDK;
        startRecognitionBtn.disabled = false;
      }
    });
  </script>
  <!-- </quickstartcode> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No the problem was with an old version of the SDK. my code works perfectly now.